# "farsi amare" vs. "farsi amato"

Tags: verbs, infinitive, passive, reflexive

I've seen that "farsi amare" means "*to make it loved*", but why wouldn't that be "*farsi amato*"?

Comment: Where did you find this? *Farsi amare* means *To make (someone)  love you*, *farsi amato* is not a common expression, but I'd interpreted it as *To become loved* with a strong archaising flavor

Comment: @DenisNardin From the motto of the religious congregation [_Suore Consolatrici del Sacro Cuore di Gesù_](https://www.consolingsisters.org/): "_Cuor di Gesù, amarTi e farTi amare!_" ("Heart of Jesus, to love Thee and make Thee loved!")

Comment: *Farti* is not the same as *farsi*.

Comment: @DenisNardin Isn't it second person vs. third person?

Comment: No, the infinitive tense does not have a person. It's reflexive voice vs active voice with a clitic object.

Comment: @DenisNardin I'm referring to that "clitic object". How would you say: "To make me loved", "To make he/she/it loved", "To make us loved", "To make y'all loved", "To make them loved"? "_Farmi amare_", "_Farsi amare_", "_Farci amare_", "_Farvi amare_", "_Farli amare_", respectively?

Comment: It's enough to look at any table of Italian pronouns (e.g. [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Italian/Grammar/Pronouns)), but for example *To make him loved* is *Farlo amare*. *si* is a reflexive pronoun and it is not used in the active voice.

Comment: @DenisNardin Then how does one say: "To make him love."?

Comment: That is also *Farlo amare*. At the infinitive the two forms are identical.

Comment: @DenisNardin Is "_farsi amato_" improper Italian?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146122/discussion-on-question-by-geremia-farsi-amare-vs-farsi-amato); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Let's continue the conversation in chat (please tag me when you get there)